# Prime divisor in positive integers sequences

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I would like to know if anyone has an ideea if the following statement is true.
For any sequence of consecutive positive integerers $(n_0, n_0+1,..., n_0+k).$ Where $n_0 \ge 1, k\ge 0,$ but $k\ge 1$ if $n_0 = 0$ (so different from the sequence (1)). There exists a prime number p that divides only one number in the sequence.

For example in the sequence (14, 15, 16) 7 divides only one of them, it doesn't have to be unique as 5 also divides only one of them.

A few restrictions that I managed to find for a counter-example to exist:

- The sequence cannot contain a prime number, otherwise it will also contain a largest prime number and that prime will only divide itself.
- k has to be smaller than $2\times n_0,$ otherwise the sequence will contain a prime number.
- The number of elements in the sequence (i.e. $k+1$) cannot be a prime number, otherwise that prime will only divide one number.

I made a simple computer program to check for such a sequence and couldn't find any in all possible sequences for up to $n_0 = 200000.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Sylvester's_theorem

Comment: Well doesn't Sylverster's theorem refers to a sequence of numbers that are less than 2(k+1)? It's just another version of the postulate and I did state that for such a sequence to exists k has to be smaller than 2 × n0

Comment: It solves a part of the problem, but the numbers have to all be greater than k. It does make it extremely restrictive for such a sequence to exist, but I can't quite put my finger on why it can't exist.

Answer (score 5):

If $n_0 > k+1$ we have Sylvester's Theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Sylvester's_theorem), see [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN599484047_0021?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[5],%22view%22:%22info%22%7D) for the original paper by Sylvester and see [here](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) for a proof by Erdős), which states that $n_0(n_0 + 1) \cdots (n_0 + k)$ is divisible by a prime $p$ bigger than $k+1$, so that exactly one element of our sequence is divisible by $p$. For $n_0 \le k+1$ we have a prime $p$ with $n_0 \le \left \lceil(n_0 + k)/2 \right\rceil < p \le n_0 + k$ by Bertrand's Postulate and no other integer in the sequence can be divisible by $p$, since $2p > n_0 + k$.

Comment: Great answer! Can you please add the link to Sylvester's Theorem to your answer so that everything's in the same place?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! Would you happen to have a demonstration for Sylvester's Theorem. He has few of them but didn't manage to find anything about it.

Comment: I have added a link to Sylvester's paper from 1892. It is not easy by any means, but I find his writing style beautiful!